# Class inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code, that works:

```
public class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue){
        cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue){
        gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment){
        speed = speed + increment;
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement){
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates(){
        System.out.println("cadence: " + cadence + "; speed: " + speed + "; gear: " + gear);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 'Bicycle' objects:
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on the two new objects:
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(45);
        bike2.speedUp(15);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }

}
```

Then I want a new class called 'MountainBike' to inherit from the class 'Bicycle', and I wrote the following new code:

```
package mountainbike;

public class MountainBike extends Bicycle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

But here I get an error indication on the line of `public class MountainBike extends Bicycle {` saying `cannot find symbol class Bicycle`.

I suppose I have to put an "import" somewhere, but what should I import exactly?

Comment: your bicycle can accelerate backwards when braking

Comment: import the package in which Bicycle class is present

Comment: if you are using eclipse, press CTRL+SHIFT+O

Comment: Do you use any IDE? Intellij/Eclipse/Netbeans?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. What do you mean by "Move Bicycle to some package aka subdirectory"? My 'Bicycle' class is in the file 'Bicycle.java' with (default) package 'bicyle', while my 'MountainBike' class is in the file 'MountainBike.java' with (default) package 'mountainbike'. Isn't that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Import the package containing Bicycle class, add this to your MauntainBike code:-

```
package mountainbike;

import packageName.Bicycle;

public class MountainBike extends Bicycle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Or If there is no package for the Bicycle class (default package),add Bicycle to the same package as that of MountainBike

```
package mountainbike;

public class Bicycle {
.
.
.
}
```

Now Bicycle is in the same package and hence visible to the MountainBike class.

Answer (score 0):

Put Bicycle class and MountainBike class in the same package, mountainbike package maybe.
Or import the package of Bicycle class on the file that defines the MountainBike class.

```
package mountainbike;
import bicycle.*; //or import bicycle.Bicycle;

public class MountainBike extends Bicycle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Check also the folder structure. Bicycle class should be in 'bicycle' folder, that corresponds to the bicycle package and MountainBike class should be in 'mountainbike' folder, that corresponds to the 'mountainbike' package. Your project structure should be the similar.

Comment: OK, but how do I import the package of 'Bicycle' class in to the file that defines the 'MountainBike' class?

Comment: What is the name of the package that contains 'Bicycle' class? If you don't have one, you better put Bicycle class in a package also. Still, it whould be better to have both classes in the same package.

Comment: My 'Bicycle' class is in the file 'Bicycle.java' with (default) package 'bicyle', while my 'MountainBike' class is in the file 'MountainBike.java' with (default) package 'mountainbike'. But it doesn't work, not even writing 'import bicycle.*;'.     How can I put both classes in the same package?

Comment: What is your project folder structure?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. I have one project called 'Bicycle', where my 'Bicycle.java' file is, and another project called 'MountainBike', where my 'MountainBike.java' file is.

Comment: In this case you should keep the import line of code and you should make the Bicycle project visible for MountainBike project. I never used NetBeans, but you must check MountainBike project properties and add Bicycle to used libraries (external libraries maybe).

Comment: OK, I've found the mistake, I had to put both classes into the same NetBeans project. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your package for `MountainBike` and `Bicycle` same ?
If not import the `Bicycle` in your `MountainBike` class.

```
import <bicycle-package>.Bicycle;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `MountainBike` class in package `mountainbike`, and your `Bicycle` class is not in this `mountainbike` package, you can get this error. One solution would be to import the package in which `Bicycle` is located. You can either type the import like

```
import com.example.bicycle.Bicycle;
```

But usually packages are used to separate unrelated classes and keep related classes together. I feel that the classes you are dealing with are related enough to be in the same package. If both are in the same package your code will work without any extra import.

Answer (score 0):

Move Bicycle to some package aka subdirectory. The **default package** (leaving out package ... and using the top directory) is not intended for such usage (yeah).

Especially one cannot do:

```
import Bicycle; // NO CAN DO - Default package import.
```

*Being able to use a fully qualified name `mountainbike.MountainBike` but not being able to use `Bicycle` was a measure to ensure that packages were used to structure classes.*